# Execute function on interval only if server is not under heavy load

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm performing a routine check on my DB every hour or so by doing

```
setInterval(function() {
  myCheckFunction();
}, 3600000)
```

I'm thinking of something like :

```
setInterval(function() {
  server.getConnections(function(err, count) {
    if (count < X) {
      myCheckFunction();
    }
}, 3600000)
```

To check if there's isn't too much work being done right now.

Is it a good idea ? 
If so what value could X have ?
If not, should I try differently or just do the test, non regarding of the current load ?

I don't expect millions of connections, this is just a proof of concept and my teacher asked me to take care of that kind of things.

Thanks !

**Edit:** Why do I want to avoid heavy load ? Because the routine check could take a couple of minutes and require a lot of work for the server. It has to contact at least 5 DNS server for each entry in the DB, request HTML code and hash it, then compare answers. The check for one entry can take up to 6 seconds due the the fact that the DNS servers can be Timeout and the DB is hosted separately from the project.

Comment: Gonna edit my question for a better understanding of the check and why I wanna avoid heavy load.

Comment: I love to edit my question for someone that delete his comment ! ;)

Comment: But that's just I/O work, isn't it? Wouldn't the node.js server be free while waiting for the DNS servers and DB server to respond?

Comment: It is during one check. But let say I've to check a 1000 entries, during one test, the server is free to check the others and so on. Since it's node, he's not waiting, he's executing all the other tests. That's why I'm worry about the clients connecting at that same time.

Comment: @brnrd sounds like you could use [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback). With that, you could make it so every check runs only when the previous check has finished, instead of running 1000 checks in parallel (or use `eachLimit` to run, say, max 5 checks in parallel, to speed things up a bit).

Comment: I'm already using async for something else, but I'll give it a shot for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

[toobusy](https://github.com/lloyd/node-toobusy)

Comment: What a great little thing ! Gonna try that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

With this particular requirements, I would perform this check on server side instead.

```
var checkFunctionCaller = function () {
    //call async function on server side and provide a callback function
    //to be called as server returns an answer
    server.myCheckFunction(function (result) {
        // if server was able to run check - it return 'done' and everything is fine
        if(result === "done") {
          //do nothing
        }
        //otherwise, re-schedule a check in five minutes
        setTimeout(checkFunctionCaller, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    });
}


setInterval(checkFunctionCaller, 3600000);
```

Comment: That's a great way to do it. But I'm not worry on the fact that the test could be done, but how it gonna delay the clients requests.The check has no reason to fail.